# Parsing SPARQL results to obtain hostname

Tags: sparql, stardog

I have a huge list of triples like this:

```
?s ex:url ?url
```

Where `?url` can be:

```
www.ex.com/data/1.html
www.ex.com/data/2.html
www.google.com/search
...
```

Is it possible, with a SPARQL query, to filter the query somehow and obtain the distinct list of domains? In the example, `www.ex.com` and `www.google.com`.

Somthing like this:

```
SELECT distinct ?url
WHERE { ?s ex:url ?url }
```

But treating each url bind. Of course I could get them all, and treat each url one by one in my program, but I suppose a sparql query would be more memory efficient. I am using Stardog - in case it has some custom functionality.

Comment: You could BIND the domain of a URL to a new variable and SELECT this variable then. See the SPARQL specs for String operations and REGEX. Something like the substring until the first occurrence of `/` should work.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how I could bind the domain of the URLs to a new variable? I know the REGEX operations, but they seem to discard results via FILTER

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [REPLACE](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-replace) with [REGEX](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-regex):

```
BIND(REPLACE(STR(?url), "^(.*?)/.*", "$1") AS ?domain)
```

[Example in Yasgui](http://yasgui.org/short/ryUMH1O1l)

Edit: As @JoshuaTailor noted in the comments, [STRBEFORE](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-strbefore) is better if there is no scheme in ?url:

```
BIND(STRBEFORE(?url, "/") AS ?domain)
```

If you need to worry about the URL scheme (this discards the scheme):

```
BIND(REPLACE(STR(?url), "^(https?://)?(.*?)/.*", "$2") AS ?domain)
```

Of course, the above only works for basic http(s) URLs, and the regex becomes somewhat more complex if arbitrary URLs need to be handled.

Here's one that handles any or missing scheme, port number, auth info, and missing trailing slash:

```
BIND(REPLACE(?url, "^(?:.*?://)?(?:.*?@)?([^:]+?)(:\\d+)?((/.*)|$)", "$1") AS ?domain)
```

Note that queries with regular expressions can be quite slow.

Comment: Your 2nd Regex works great! Thanks! The 1st one only returns http:// so I suspect it needs further tunning for my case, but the 2nd is good. I will do a performance test because as you said it might be very costly

Comment: There's no need for regex here.  You can just use STRBEFORE and get the string before `/`.  And the second REGEX doesn't work for non-HTTP(S) URLs, such as `ftp`, etc.  This would also have issues with URLs that include authentication information and port information (e.g., `http://user:password@example.org:8080/index.html`, where you'd get `user:password@example.org:8080`.

Comment: By the way, the 1st one should work too for my question - my mistake, I forgot that the real data has the schema (http://...)

Answer (score 5):

You can do something like this using string manipulation that doesn't require regular expressions.  E.g., you can take the part of the string form of the URL after a "//" and before a "/":

```sql
select ?url ?hostname {
  values ?url { <http://example.org/index.html> }
  bind(strbefore(strafter(str(?url),"//"),"/") as ?hostname)
}
```

```
---------------------------------------------------
| url                             | hostname      |
===================================================
| <http://example.org/index.html> | "example.org" |
---------------------------------------------------
```

That doesn't use regular expressions, and might be faster than a solution using the **regex** function.

However, this might still get you more than a hostname, e.g., if the URL is something like **http://username:password@example.org:8080**, where you'd get **username:password@example.org:8080**, which is more than just hostname.

To do this more carefully, you'd want to pick one of the URI/URL, etc., specifications, such as [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986), and have a look at the section on syntax components.  A few relevant productions from that grammar are:

> ```
> URI         = scheme ":" hier-part [ "?" query ] [ "#" fragment ]
>
>       hier-part   = "//" authority path-abempty
>                   / path-absolute
>                   / path-rootless
>                   / path-empty
> ```
>
> The authority component is preceded by a double slash ("//") and is
> terminated by the next slash ("/"), question mark ("?"), or number
> sign ("#") character, or by the end of the URI.
>
> ```
> authority   = [ userinfo "@" ] host [ ":" port ]
> ```

I won't work through all that (and maybe it would make more sense to use a regular expression to handle the complex cases), but it might be easiest to just take the URI from the SPARQL result and then use an actual URI parsing library to get the hostname.  That's the most reliable solution, since URIs can be pretty complex.

Comment: STRBEFORE+STRAFTER does not work if the URL is not complete (missing scheme), as in the examples in the question. Although apparently this was not the case in the actual data.

Comment: I agree with your last paragraph. Using a URI parsing library sounds like the most robust way to program this. I will check your solution too and measure all times to see what of the 3 options perform better. Thanks