# How to extract the working place from a given Email Address in SPARQL

Tags: regex, sparql, ontology

For Example: "**john@mora.org**" is the email address and,  I want to extract **mora** from this email using SPARQL

This is my approach which didn't give the expected result:

```
BASE <http://timbl.org/foaf.rdf>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
SELECT ?name ?work_place
FROM <http://timbl.org/foaf.rdf>
WHERE
{
<#timbl> foaf:knows ?friend .
?friend foaf:name ?name .
?friend foaf:mbox ?mail .
BIND(REPLACE(STR(?mail), "^.*@", "", "i") as ?work_place) .
}
```

Example input:

```
"john@mora.org"
```

Expected Result:

```
"mora"
```

The result I Received :

```
"mora.org"
```

What needed to be added in the query or RegEx to get the expected output

Comment: given that SPARQL does support `regex`, just use it.

Comment: @UninformedUser yes that is what I want how that can be retrieved using regex in sparql?

Comment: the pattern to use is `BIND (REPLACE("THE_STRING_HERE", "THE_REGEX_HERE", "THE_REGEX_GROUP_HERE") AS ?str)` in your SPARQL query

Comment: @UninformedUser what should I be adding to "The_REGEX_HERE" and "THE_REGEX_GROUP_HERE"?

Comment: BIND(REPLACE(?email_address, "[^@]*$") AS ?work_place) . whats wrong with this?

Comment: it takes 3 arguments if you look carefully at my comment. I mean, you want to extract something, right? The 3rd argument should be the regex group that you want to use to replace the whole string

Comment: The function `REPLACE( string, pattern, replacement, flag )` returns the string after replacing all occurrences of `pattern` in `string` with `replacement`. The `replacement` can contain `$n` or `${name}`, which are replaced by the corresponding numbered or named capture group in the pattern. An optional flag affects the regular expression pattern, just as with the flag argument to REGEX().

Comment: @UninformedUser BIND(REPLACE(?email_address, "[^@]*$") AS ?work_place) .why this wont work?

Comment: because it takes **3 argument**, not just two. The signature is `REPLACE( string, pattern, replacement, flag )` with `flag` being optional. One more time, this method does replace in the given `string` all matches of the `pattern` by the given `replacement` - this is pretty trivial. If you do `REPLACE( "abab", "a", "d")` it returns `"dbdb"`

Comment: Does this answer your question?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40180792/parsing-sparql-results-to-obtain-hostname

Comment: @tink no that didn't help. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your approach only deleted the part of the string you matched, if you also wanna match and delete another substring you can just nest your replaces. Something like this should work.

```
 BASE    <http://timbl.org/foaf.rdf>
 PREFIX  foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
 
 SELECT  ?name ?work_place
 FROM <>
 WHERE
   { <#timbl>  foaf:knows  ?friend .
     ?friend   foaf:name   ?name ;
               foaf:mbox   ?mail
     BIND(replace(replace(str(?mail), "^.*@", "", "i"), "\..*$", "", "i") AS ?work_place)
   }
```